# Setting `immediate.` to `TRUE` with condition object in R?

Tags: r, exception

I am trying to signal a custom condition in R using a condition object. However, it seems that I cannot set the `immediate.` argument to `TRUE`, nor can I alter any other argument to the `stop`, `warning`, etc functions. Is there a way to use condition objects but still retain the other arguments of `stop`, `warning`, and `message` ?

*MWE:*

Warning in perhaps the "usual" way works as expected, meaning that the warnings occur at each iteration. **This is what I desire.**

```
# Works as expected
for(i in 1:20){warning("A warning", immediate.=T) ; Sys.sleep(.1)}
>Warning: A warning
>Warning: A warning
>Warning: A warning
>Warning: A warning
>Warning: A warning
... [truncated]
```

---

In contrast, when using a condition object below, the warnings are collected and then we're told that there are 20 of them at the end:

**Attempt 1**

```
# Does not signal warning immediately 
cond = structure(list(message="A warning", call=NULL, immediate.=T), class=c("warning", "condition"))

for(i in 1:20){ warning(cond); Sys.sleep(.1) }
>There were 20 warnings (use warnings() to see them)
```

---

**Attempt 2** -- Setting the argument manually

```
 for(i in 1:20) {warning(cond, immediate.=T); Sys.sleep(.1)}
>additional arguments ignored in warning()
>additional arguments ignored in warning()
>...[truncated]
>There were 20 warnings (use warnings() to see them)
```

---

**Attempt 3** -- Deleting the `immediate.=T` argument from the `cond` object, and retrying (2)

```
cond = structure(list(message="A warning", call=NULL), class=c("warning", "condition"))

for(i in 1:20) {warning(cond, immediate.=T); Sys.sleep(.1)}
>additional arguments ignored in warning()
>additional arguments ignored in warning()
>...[truncated]
>There were 20 warnings (use warnings() to see them)
```

Is there a way to use condition objects but still retain the other arguments of `stop`, `warning`, and `message` ?

Comment: I would post your edit as an answer below. If people have a different answer they can also post it. This might be a better question for the `R-devel` mailing list as I do believe there are planned changes for the handling of conditions in future R releases.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the heads-up. How would I go about posing this question to the `R-devel` mailing list? I am unfamiliar with that in its entirety. Is there some link in Stack Overflow for this?

Answer (score 1):

Okay so I have found a workaround/solution that gets the job done, although it is somewhat inelegant. In any case, the solution that works consists of:

1. Wrapping the warning in a `tryCatch` block
2. Capture the warning condition object
3. Modify the captured object from (2) as needed
4. Re-warn using the modified object from (3)

```
# Set immediate. to false, collects warnings as expected
my.call = "A call"

for(i in 1:20){

  tryCatch(warning("A warning", immediate.=F),
           warning = function(w){w$call <- my.call; warning(w)}
           )

  Sys.sleep(.1)
  
} 

>There were 20 warnings (use warnings() to see them)


# changing immediate. to true, warns at each iteration as desired
for(i in 1:20){

  tryCatch(warning("A warning", immediate.=T),
           warning = function(w){w$call <- my.call; warning(w)}
           )

  Sys.sleep(.1)
  
} 

>Warning in "A call" : A warning
>Warning in "A call" : A warning
>Warning in "A call" : A warning
>...[truncated]
```